# apache phoenix 4.10 column mapping from hbase

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a existing hbase table, already put all data in phoenix format. then try to create a phoenix table on top of it. in phoenix 4.9 everything is fine. But phoenix 4.10 has a column mapping https://blogs.apache.org/phoenix/entry/column-mapping-and-immutable-data, so my column qualifer can not be the original string like address,name,etc. but has to map to certain integer, how do I do that? is there a way to disable this column mapping?

Answer (score 2):

figured out, the phoenix SYSTEM.CATALOG table has this mapping as column_qualifier, need to use this when save from hbase